# How can I give a background Image to my View in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI and iOS and I'm having trouble getting my VStack to stack items properly. Mainly, it looks like the image on the top left is too big. Here's a screenshot of the size of the image in my layout:

[image: layout image]

This is what it should look like:

[image: what layout should look like]

This is the SwiftUI code:

```
    @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    @State private var isEditing = false
    var body: some View {
        return VStack(content: {
            
            Image("UIBubble")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 217, height: 184, alignment: .leading)
                .position(x: 108, y: 92);

            Text("PET SUPPORT").font(Font.custom("Permanent Marker", size: 36))
                .foregroundColor(Color.petSupportText)
                .padding()
                .frame(width: .infinity, height: 0, alignment: .center);
            
            Text("EMAIL").font(Font.custom("Permanent Marker", size: 18))
                .padding(.top, 20)
                .padding(.horizontal, 0)
                .frame(width: .infinity, height: 0, alignment: .leading);
            
            TextField("Email", text: $email) {
                isEditing in self.isEditing = isEditing
            }
            .autocapitalization(.none)
            .disableAutocorrection(true)
            .padding(.horizontal, 30)
            .padding(.top, 20);
            
            Divider()
                .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                .foregroundColor(.black);
            
            Text("PASSWORD").font(Font.custom("Permanent Marker", size: 18)).padding(.top, 50).padding(.horizontal, 0).frame(width: .infinity, height: 20, alignment: .leading);
            
            TextField("Password", text: $password) {
                isEditing in self.isEditing = isEditing
            }
            .autocapitalization(.none)
            .disableAutocorrection(true)
            .padding(.horizontal, 30)
            .padding(.top, 20)
            
            Divider().padding(.horizontal, 30).foregroundColor(.black);
            
        })
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
```

Image giving me trouble:

[image: bubble image]

The image itself is 217x184.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use ZStack for this work or send the Image to background like in code:

*Also I made some code for you to make you free to use that file Image and you get same and much more better result with system shape. you can change the Color, shape, size, number of bubble and every thing . .*

---

[image]

---

with usage of **contrast**: make the Color like your Color

### [image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    @State private var showPassword = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        return VStack(content: {
            
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: 100)
            
            Text("PET SUPPORT")
                .font(Font.custom("Permanent Marker", size: 36))
                .padding()
            
            Group {
                
                HStack {
                    
                    Text("EMAIL")
                        .font(Font.custom("Permanent Marker", size: 18))
                        .padding(.top, 20)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                }
                
                TextField("Email", text: $email)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .keyboardType(.emailAddress)      // <<: Here:  A type optimized for multiple email address entry (shows space @ . prominently).
                    .padding(.top, 20)
                
                
                Divider()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                
            }
            
            
            Group {
                
                HStack {
                    
                    Text("PASSWORD")
                        .font(Font.custom("Permanent Marker", size: 18))
                        .padding(.top, 50)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                }
                
                ZStack {
                    
                    if showPassword {
                        TextField("Password", text: $password)
                    }
                    else {
                        SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    }
                    
                }
                .frame(height: 20)
                .overlay(Image(systemName: showPassword ? "eye.slash" : "eye").onTapGesture { showPassword.toggle() }, alignment: .trailing)
                .autocapitalization(.none)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .padding(.top, 20)
                
                Divider()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                
            }
            
            
            
            Group {
                
                Button("Sign Up") {}
                    .padding()
                
                Button("Login") {}
                    .padding()
                
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
        })
        .padding(.horizontal, 30)
        .background(bubble, alignment: .topLeading)
        .background(bubble.rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 180)), alignment: .bottomTrailing)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .statusBar(hidden: true)
        
    }

    var bubble: some View {   // <<: you can put this part out and use update code for this part

        Image("UIBubble")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 217, height: 184, alignment: .leading)

    }
    
}
```

---

**Update:** you can replace that file Image with high quality system shape like this code!

```
var bubble: some View {
   
    ZStack {
        
        Circle()
            .fill(Color(UIColor.systemTeal).opacity(0.2))   // <<: Here: opacity = 0.2
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
            .offset(x: -100, y: -180)
        
        
        Circle()
            .fill(Color(UIColor.systemTeal).opacity(0.2))   // <<: Here: opacity = 0.2
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
            .offset(x: -180, y: -100)
        
    }
    .contrast(3.0)           // <<: Here: This make your Color POP out!

}
```

---

**Update 2**: with this down code your **Circle/bubble** came to live and they move with smooth animation.

```
@State private var startAnimation: Bool = false

var bubble: some View {
    
    ZStack {
        
        Circle()
            .fill(Color(UIColor.systemTeal).opacity(0.2))   // <<: Here: opacity = 0.2
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
            .offset(x: startAnimation ? -110 : -100, y: startAnimation ? -180 : -150)
        
        
        Circle()
            .fill(Color(UIColor.systemTeal).opacity(0.2))   // <<: Here: opacity = 0.2
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
            .offset(x: startAnimation ? -180 : -150, y: startAnimation ? -90 : -100)
        
    }
    .contrast(3.0)                   // <<: Here: This make your Color POP out!
    .onAppear() { startAnimation = true }
    .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 3.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: true))
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the image size issue but it moves the image and the first VStack to center horizontally. How could I move it to the very left like in the layout image in my question?

Comment: @DayemSaeed: I think I just solved your all issue try the code now.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's such an impressive and detailed answer!

Comment: @DayemSaeed: your are welcome, I am updating your keyboard method as well. I will update my code in some min.

Comment: I honestly can't overstate how thankful I am. I've been staring at this like an idiot because I'm just so happy with the layout! Plus I learned about Groups and how to properly use stacks, spacers, and dividers. Thank you so so so much!

Comment: @DayemSaeed: No problem at all, all of us started at same point, I improved your keyboard.

Comment: thank you for all your help! I had another issue when I started using a NavigationView. Could you help me on chat or something?

Comment: Thank you so much! I created a room on https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230283/room-for-dayem-saeed-and-swiftpunk

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can just use [`background(alignment:content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/background(alignment:content:)) modifier

So, add this background modifiers to your view:

```swift
VStack {
    ...
}
.background(alignment: .topLeading) {
    Image("UIBubble")
}
.background(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
    Image("UIBubble2"),
}
```

In my opinion this solution is the most *swifty*